# Trying to find a minimum of g(x) function and the x value at this minimum

Tags: python, error-handling, sympy, minimum

I am trying to find a minimum of a created function *g(alpha)* and what is more important, to find value of the *alpha* at this minimum, or close to the minimum.

The code I use is the following: it creates function *f*, vectors *D*,*avec* and *grad* and uses it for creation of function *g(alpha)*, minimum of which I want to find, together with the *alpha* value.

The problem is that after applying *solve* from sympy library I don't get numerical number of *alpha*. Instead of I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin
from sympy import Symbol, solve
from scipy import interpolate

Emax = 10
bins = 200
x = np.linspace(1, Emax, num = Emax, dtype=np.int)   #create grid of indexes
y = np.linspace(1, bins, num = bins, dtype=np.int)
z = np.random.rand(bins, Emax)                       # random matrix   
f = interpolate.interp2d(x,y,z, kind='cubic')        # make the matrix continious

D= np.zeros(bins)
D = 2*f(1.5, y)  # create vector
avec = np.array([4.0, 16.0])  
grad = np.array([1e-5,1e-5])

g= lambda alpha: np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(D,  (avec[0]-alpha*grad[0])*f((avec[1]- 
                                          alpha*grad[1]),y))))

oo= fmin(g,(0.0))

alfa = Symbol("alfa")
slv= solve((np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(D,  (avec[0]-alfa*grad[0])*f((avec[1]- 
                                          alfa*grad[1]),y)))) - oo), alfa)
```

I know that this solution may not be the best for this problem. I'm new in Python and if you have any better suggestions how to find *alpha* here, please tell me.

Comment: isn't it just `g(oo)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are really confusing what `sympy` does. `sympy` is a module to solve and print analytical equations. You do not need to use that package at all for this task.

You actually do find the minimum of `g` here. You store this result in `oo`.

So basically, delete the last 2 lines starting `alfa = ...` and `slv = ...` and then just put `print(oo)`. `oo` is the value you are looking for, the value of alpha which minimises the function `g`

Comment: I thought that *oo* contains the minimum value of the function g(alpha), not  alpha itself, am I wrong?

Comment: Oh now I see, yes.
Thank you, you are right. I just complicated it without no need..